# php soap client How to change namespace prefix?

Tags: php, xml, soap, laravel-5, soap-client

I want send xml like this through the soup client:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:hot="http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <hot:Credentials UserName="test" Password="test@123"/>
      <wsa:Action>http://test/HotelBookingApi/CountryListRequest</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:To>http://api.test.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>

   <soap:Body>
      <hot:CountryListRequest/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But it send xml like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi">
    <env:Header>
        <ns1:Credentials UserName="test" Password="test@123"/>
        <ns1:Action>http://test/HotelBookingApi/HotelSearch</ns1:Action>
        <ns1:To>http://api.test.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc</ns1:To>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:CountryListRequest/>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

api need exact same xml like the first one.I use Laravel 5.2 and this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Hotel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use SoapClient;
use SoapHeader;
use SoapVar;

class HotelTBO extends Model
{

    //Credentials
    var $Credentials = ['UserName' => 'test', 'Password' => 'test@123'];

    //WSDL
    var $wsdl = 'http://api.tbotechnology.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc?wsdl';

    //Actions
    var $ActionHotelSearch = "http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/HotelSearch";

    //NS
    var $NS = "http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi";

    //TO
    var $ToHotelSearch = "http://api.tbotechnology.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc";

    public function testSearch()
    {

        $client = new SoapClient(public_path('\assets\file\TBO.wsdl'), array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0));


        $HeaderVar = new SoapVar($this->HeaderXML, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);

        $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($this->NS, "Credentials", $this->Credentials,false);
        $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($this->NS, "Action", $this->ActionHotelSearch);
        $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($this->NS, "To", $this->ToHotelSearch);

        $client->__setSoapHeaders($Headers);
        $result = $client->__soapCall('CountryList', []);


    }
```

There's a package called https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap but there are no any documentation for that. 
many thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried building the XML string manually and replacing the credentials in the string with your variables? I had the same issue where I tried a bunch of packages that deal with WSDL services before I ended up building the XML string and posting it using CURL.

Comment: yeah that's how i'm gonna do it now

Comment: If the XML is not exactly the same, do you get an error?  Namespace prefixes are essentially just variables so it should work no matter what is used.

Comment: yeah api mismatch error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve only using PHP soap client.

Answer (score 0):

using nusoap parameters must be configured

https://github.com/pwnlabs/nusoap

add global name space

`$client->namespaces['tem'] = "http://tempuri.org/";`

and add local namespace for elements

```
 $dom  = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
            $document = $dom->createElement('tem:CAV_GET_DATA');
            $document = $dom->appendChild($document);
            $el = $dom->createElement("tem:UsuarioID", '111');
            $document->appendChild($el);
            $el = $dom->createElement("tem:Password", '111');
            $document->appendChild($el);
            $el = $dom->createElement("tem:idEmpleado", 111);
            $document->appendChild($el);
            $param = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Example complete

```
 $client = new nusoap_client('urlexamplee?WSDL', 'wsdl');
            $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
            $client->response_timeout = 300
            $namespaces['tem'] = "http://tempuri.org/";

$dom  = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
                $document = $dom->createElement('tem:CAV_GET_DATA');
                $document = $dom->appendChild($document);
                $el = $dom->createElement("tem:UsuarioID", '111');
                $document->appendChild($el);
                $el = $dom->createElement("tem:Password", '111');
                $document->appendChild($el);
                $el = $dom->createElement("tem:idEmpleado", 111);
                $document->appendChild($el);
                $param = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

 $responseService = $this->client->call(
                'CAV_GET_DATA',
                $param

            );
```

Reequest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns6704="tem"><SOAP-ENV:Body><tem:CAV_GET_DATA><tem:UsuarioID>example</tem:UsuarioID><tem:Password>example</tem:Password><tem:idEmpleado>000000</tem:idEmpleado></tem:CAV_GET_DATA></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -1):

What error do you receive while sending your request? With this code:

```
public function testSearch()
{

    $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
    $cred_ns = 'http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi';
    $action_ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing';

    $credentialHeader = ['UserName' => 'test', 'Password' => 'test@123'];
    $actionHeader = 'http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/CountryList';
    $toHeader = 'http://api.test.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc';

    $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($cred_ns, 'Credentials', $credentialHeader , false);
    $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($action_ns, "Action", $actionHeader, false);
    $Headers[] = new SoapHeader($action_ns, "To", $toHeader, false);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($Headers);
    $result = $client->__soapCall('CountryList', []);
    print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
    echo PHP_EOL;
    print_r($result);
}
```

I receive request like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Header>
      <ns1:Credentials UserName="test" Password="test@123"/>
      <ns2:Action>http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/CountryList</ns2:Action>
      <ns2:To>http://api.test.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc</ns2:To>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:CountryListRequest/>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And authorisation error as the result:
stdClass Object

```
(
[Status] => stdClass Object
    (
        [StatusCode] => 02
        [Description] => LoginErr: Login Failed.
    )
)
```

Comment: It would be very useful for me to get information about reason of downvoting to avoid such mistakes in future.

Comment: I think it's because you didn't directly answer the question: "How to change namespace prefix"?  If you know how to do it in PHP, change your answer.  Your resulting XML still has the same namespace prefixes the OP is trying to get rid of.

Comment: O, I get it. Thank you for your answer. However due to the fact that I received authorisation error (not api mismatch error) with old namespaces I suggested that the problem could be in other place, not in namespaces.